# Fastest way to transfer large amounts of data between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 2 worksheets, for simplicity sake let's call them `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in the explanations. In `Sheet1` I have around 50k rows of data. I am trying to go through `Sheet1` and find unique occurrences in the data set to then transfer across to `Sheet2`.

Below are the methods I have used so far and their rough estimates for time taken.

Method A - Iterate through `Sheet1` with a `For` loop with the conditional check programmed in VBA, if condition is met - transfer a range of 8 cells on that row to `Sheet2`. This method completes 60% in 60 minutes.

Method B - I thought that removing the condition check in VBA could speed things up so I created a new column in `Sheet1` with an `IF` statement that returns "Y" if the condition is met. I then iterate through this column and if there is a "Y" - transfer the occurrence across to `Sheet2`. This weirdly takes longer than method A, namely 50% in 60 mins.

```
Sub NewTTS()

Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim i As Long

With wsOTS

    lRow1 = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lRow1 To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("P" & i).Text = "Y" Then
            lRow2 = wsTTS.Range("E" & wsTTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            wsTTS.Range("E" & lRow2, "AA" & lRow2).Value = .Range("E" & i, "AA" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Method C - I then read on another post that the `.Find()` method is quicker than using `For` loop method. As such I used a `.Find()` in the column that returns the "Y" and then transfer event across to `Sheet2`. This is the fastest method so far but still only completes 75% in 60 mins.

```
Sub SearchOTS()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim startNumber As Long
Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim startTime As Double

startTime = Time

lRow1 = wsOTS.Range("E" & wsOTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Columns("P:P").Select

Selection.Find(What:="Y", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

startNumber = ActiveCell.Row

lRow2 = wsTTS.Range("E" & wsTTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wsTTS.Range("E" & lRow2, "AA" & lRow2).Value = wsOTS.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row, "AA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

For i = 1 To lRow1
    Selection.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

    If ActiveCell.Row = startNumber Then GoTo ProcessComplete

    lRow2 = wsTTS.Range("E" & wsTTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsTTS.Range("E" & lRow2, "AA" & lRow2).Value = wsOTS.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row, "AA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    wsOTS.Range("B18").Value = i / lRow1
Next i

ProcessComplete:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Complete! Time taken: " & Format(Time - startTime, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Method D - I then read another post saying that the fastest way would be to build an array and then loop through the array. Instead of an array I used a collection (dynamic), and I iterate through `Sheet1` and store the row numbers for the occurences. I then loop through the collection and transfer the events across to `Sheet2`. This method returns 50% in 60 mins.

```
Sub PleaseWork()

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim myCol As New Collection

lRow1 = wsOTS.Range("E" & wsOTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'build collection of row numbers
For i = 1 To lRow1
    If wsOTS.Range("P" & i).Text = "Y" Then
        myCol.Add i
    End If
Next i

'now go through collection and build TTS
For i = 1 To myCol.Count
    lRow2 = wsTTS.Range("E" & wsTTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsTTS.Range("E" & lRow2, "N" & lRow2).Value = wsOTS.Range("E" & myCol(i), "N" & myCol(i)).Value
Next i

Set myCol = New Collection

End Sub
```

I am trying to find the fastest way to complete this task but all the methods I have tried are yielding greater than an hour to complete.

Is there anything I am missing here? Is there a faster method?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381841/10540017

Comment: Put everything in an array, do the processing there, and write back to the sheet when done.

Comment: I don't know if it would be faster, but have you tried an `Advanced Filter`? One of the output options is to write the results to a different location. And if it is fastest, you could code it in VBA if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a range is abysmally slow, and the cause for your long runtime. If you already know that you are going to read 1000 rows, do not read them one at a time. Instead, pull the whole range in a buffer, then work only with that buffer. Same goes for writing. If you do not know in advance how much you will write, make chunks of e.g. 100 rows length.

(<s>Untested</s>) example:

```
Sub PleaseWork()

    Dim i As Long, j as long
    Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim myCol As New Collection
    Dim column_p() as variant
    dim inbuffer() as Variant
    dim outbuffer() as variant

    lRow1 = wsOTS.Range("E" & wsOTS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Get whole Column P at once
    column_p = wsOTS.Range("P1").Resize(lRow1, 1).Value

    'build collection of row numbers
    For i = 1 To lRow1
        If column_p(i, 1) = "Y" Then
            myCol.Add i
        End If
    Next i

    'now go through collection and build TTS
    lRow2 = myCol.Count 'Number of required rows
    ' get whole input range
    inbuffer = wsOTS.Range("E1").Resize(lRow1, 10).Value
    ' prepare output
    ReDim outbuffer(1 to lRow2, 1 to 10)
    For i = 1 To myCol.Count
        ' write into outbuffer
        for j = 1 to 10
            outbuffer(i, j) = inbuffer(myCol(i), j)
        Next
    Next i

    ' Set whole output at once
    wsTTS.Range("E1").Resize(lRow2, 10).Value = outbuffer

    Set myCol = New Collection

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW dude, this is great. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

did you consider using **Remove Duplicates**.

Steps:

- Copy entire data to a new sheet
- On Data tab, choose Remove duplicates

You can record this as a macro as well.
[image]

Comment: In his code you can see clearly he is trying to get some rows which contain certain criteria on a given cell. Your answer won't help in any way to the OP's question.

Comment: in his explanation in the first para, he didn't mention it. excuse my oversight.