# Performance of Excel Array and small VBA Loop vs. Big VBA Loop w/o Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-2016

I've got two worksheets. The first (Calculation) contains 10.000 rows with a lot of RTD formulas and different calculations. The second (observer) observes the first one.
I've got a VBA script that runs every second and checks every row of worksheet 1 (Calculation). If the loop finds some marked data on worksheet 1 then it will copy some data from WS1 to WS2.

Solution 1: Loop checking 10.000 rows

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For I = 1 To 10000
    If CStr(.Cells(I, 1)) = "X" Then
        'DO SOME SUFF (copy the line from WS 1 to WS2)
        'Find first empty row
        LR2 = WS2.Cells(15, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
        'Copy data from WS1 to WS2
        WS1.Range(.Cells(I, 1), .Cells(I, 14)).Copy
        WS2.Cells(LR2, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Solution 2: Array function with a small loop
Can I use, instead of the 10.000 row loop, an Excel Array to observe the 10.000 rows and do some stuff with the smaller array.

On worksheet 2, I would have this code: (A1:O15)

```vb
{=index(Calculation!A$1:$O$10000; .....)....))}
```

Again I would have a smaller loop through the 15 lines of array function:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For K = 1 To 15
    If CStr(.Cells(I, 1)) = "X" Then
        'Find first empty row
        LR2 = WS2.Cells(15, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
        'Copy data from WS1 to WS2
        WS1.Range(.Cells(I, 1), .Cells(I, 14)).Copy
        WS2.Cells(LR2, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I would like to know what solution has the better performance.

I am not sure if an Excel array over 10.000 rows has a good performance. For sure the 15-rowLoop is faster than a 10000-row-Loop.

I don't know how to measure if a 15-row Loop in connection with an array (observing 10.000 rows) is faster.

Comment: What was the result of timing it (with a watch)? Both “in blink of an eye”, or is one noticeably slower? Not really much point refining the timing of the difference is significant.. or caring if not noticed, unless it will be run many many many times.

Comment: My opinion is that array formula `{=index(Calculation!A$1:$O$10000; .....)....))}` is really heavy for excel to calculate, I would not recommend to use it on larget set. If you are very keen on performance my recommendation would be to create an VBA array. [Performance difference between looping range vs looping array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302962/performance-difference-between-looping-range-vs-looping-array). I've just converted a work macro from loop to array solution and the speed performance is significant. For 45 000 rows I save between 50-20 min.

Comment: Please, try explaining what "DO SOME SUFF (copy the line from WS 1 to WS2)" means. The most time and resources consuming would be the way your code writes in WS2. If the processed result would be added at the end of the worksheet, an array to be loaded and drop the result at once will help a lot. If it is necessary to copy from row x of the fist worksheet to the same row of the second one, the array solution is better but not excelent. I mean, for 100k range, iteration itself takes less then a second and the array one about 10 milliseconds. Important is the way your code writes to `WS2`.

Comment: @Wizhi: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: @FaneDuru My Script is copying some cells from WS1 to WS2. (I edited the original post a little bit - see above)

Comment: @user2864740 the script will run many times. (Every single second) Round about 30.000-40.000 times per day.

Comment: When you calculate `LR21` as `LR2 = WS2.Cells(15, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1`, do you really want to copy in the first empty row (some other rows existing after it), or **in the last empty row of A:A column**? If the last empty row, a better way of calculating it would be `LR2 = WS2.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlup).Row + 1`. And, yes, in your case the array solution will work and cand be very fast. If this is your case, I will post an answer.  If not, please better explain what you need.

Comment: @FaneDuru I worked with the first empty row, cause I am deleting some of the rows in WS2 sometimes. But I can work with the last empty row as well. thats fine for me.

Comment: Nobody stops you to delete rows. Important is to know that you need the last empty row to paste all the processed array. Please, test the code I posted. It must be extremely fast, even for 100k, not for only 10k. It will process all the existing range. Not up to 10000 rows...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going back to column **A** 10,000 times, bring all the values into a 1D VBA array and then loop over that array:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim rng As Range, arr
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Calculation").Range("A1:A10000")
    arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng)
    
    For i = 1 To 10000
        If arr(i) = "X" Then
            'do some stuff
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If there are very few **X**'s then it may be nearly instantaneous.

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Chris Neilsen's comment, here is a version that does not use `Transpose()`:

```
Sub whatever2()
    Dim rng As Range, arr

    Set rng = Sheets("Calculation").Range("A1:A10000")
    arr = rng

    For i = 1 To 10000
        If arr(i, 1) = "X" Then
            'do some stuff
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use the slow Transpose, when you could just use the 2D array: `arr(i, 1)`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow. @chrisneilsen Is transpose really slow?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy to Sheet With Criteria

- Copies each row of a dataset in a worksheet containing a specified value (`Criteria`) in a specified column, to another worksheet.
- Adjust the values in the constants section of `createReport`.
- The data transfer will only (always) happen when the worksheet "`Observer`" is activated e.g. when another sheet is currently selected and the "`Observer`" tab is clicked on.
- This code took about 5 seconds for a million (all) rows, and under a second for 100.000 rows on my machine.
- The efficiency can further be improved by using the code with the `Worksheet Change` event in the "`Calculation`" worksheet and by turning off certain `Application` events (e.g. `.ScreenUpdating`, `.Calculation`, `.EnableEvents`).

**Excel Test Setup (Worksheet "Calculation")**

```
[A1:I1] ="Column "&COLUMN()
[A2]    =IF(I2=1,"X","Y")
[B2:H2] =RANDBETWEEN(1,1000)
[I2]    =RANDBETWEEN(1,100)
```

**Sheet Module (Worksheet "Observer")**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    createReport
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createReport()
    
    ' Constants
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Calculation"
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "X"
    Const srcFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Observer"
    Const tgtFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const includeHeaders As Boolean = True
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Source Range ('rng').
    
    ' Define Source First Cell ('cel').
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirstCellAddress)
    ' Define the Current Region ('rng') 'around' First Cell.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = cel.CurrentRegion
    ' Define Source Range ('rng') i.e. exclude cells to the left and above
    ' of Source First Cell from the Current Region.
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - cel.Row + rng.Row, _
                         rng.Columns.Count - cel.Column + rng.Column) _
                 .Offset(cel.Row - rng.Row, cel.Column - rng.Column)

    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array ('Data').
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Write resulting values from Data Array to Data Array
    ' i.e. 'shift' them to the beginning.
    
    Dim NoC As Long             ' Number of Columns
    NoC = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim i As Long               ' Source Data Rows Counter
    Dim j As Long               ' Source/Target Data Columns Counter
    Dim CurrentRow As Long      ' Target Data Rows Counter
    Dim checkHeaders As Long
    checkHeaders = -CLng(includeHeaders) ' True is '-1' in VBA.
    CurrentRow = checkHeaders
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Data(i, CriteriaColumn) = Criteria Then
            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
            For j = 1 To NoC
                ' 'Shift' from 'i' to 'CurrentRow'.
                Data(CurrentRow, j) = Data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range ('rng').
    
    ' Define Target First Cell ('cel').
    Set cel = wb.Worksheets(tgtName).Range(tgtFirstCellAddress)
    ' Define Target First Row ('rng').
    Set rng = cel.Resize(, NoC)
    ' Clear contents in columns.
    rng.Resize(rng.Worksheet.Rows.Count - cel.Row + 1).ClearContents
    
    Select Case CurrentRow
        Case 0
            GoTo CriteriaNotFound
        Case checkHeaders
            ' Write headers from Data Array to Target Range.
            rng.Resize(CurrentRow).Value = Data
            GoTo CriteriaNotFound
        Case Else
            ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
            rng.Resize(CurrentRow).Value = Data
            GoTo Success
    End Select

    ' Exit.

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
    
    ' Inform user.

CriteriaNotFound:
    MsgBox "Value '" & Criteria & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Fail"
    GoTo ProcExit
Success:
    MsgBox CurrentRow - checkHeaders & " row(s) of data transferred.", _
           vbInformation, "Success"
    GoTo ProcExit
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the next code, please. It should be very fast, using arrays and everything happening in memory. The code assumes that you need to copy all occurrences starting with the last empty cell of `WS2`:

```
Sub CopyFromWS1ToWs2Array()
  Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, searchStr As String
  Dim LR2 As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
  
  Set WS1 = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  Set WS2 = WS1.Next    'use here your necessary sheet. I used this only for testing reason
  lastRow = WS1.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of the first sheet
  
  arr1 = WS1.Range("A1:N" & lastRow).Value           'put the range in an array
  ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr1, 2), 1 To UBound(arr1)) 'redim the array to be returned
                                                      'columns and rows are reversed because
                                                      'only the second dimension can be Redim Preserve(d)
  
  searchStr = "X"      'setting the search string
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
   If arr1(i, 1) = searchStr Then
        k = k + 1 'the array row is incremented (in fact, it is the column now...)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
            arr2(j, k) = arr1(i, j) 'the row is loaded with all the necessary values
        Next j
   End If
 Next i
 'the final array is Redim, preserving only the existing values:
 ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To UBound(arr1, 2), 1 To k)
 LR2 = WS2.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row of the second worksheet
 'Dropping the array content at once (the fastest way of copying):
 WS2.Range("A" & LR2).Resize(UBound(arr2, 2), UBound(arr2)).Value = _
                                      WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr2)
 WS2.Activate: WS2.Range("A" & LR2).Select
 MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next code, which should also solve your last requests (as I understood them):

```
Sub CopyFromWS1ToWs2ArrayBis()
  Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, searchStr As String
  Dim LR2 As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arrWS2 As Variant
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long, s As Long, boolFound As Boolean
  
  Set WS1 = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  Set WS2 = WS1.Next    'use here your necessary sheet. I used this only for testing reason
  lastRow = WS1.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of the first sheet
  LR2 = WS2.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row   'last empty row of the second worksheet
  
  arr1 = WS1.Range("A1:N" & lastRow).Value            'put the range of WS1 in an array
  ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr1, 2), 1 To UBound(arr1)) 'redim the array to be returned
                                                      'columns and rows are reversed because
                                                      'only the second dimension can be Redim Preserve(d)
  arrWS2 = WS2.Range("A1:N" & LR2).Value   'put the range of WS2 in an array
  searchStr = "X"                          'setting the search string
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
   If arr1(i, 1) = searchStr Then
        For s = 1 To UBound(arrWS2)
            If arr1(i, 1) = arrWS2(s, 1) And arr1(i, 2) = arrWS2(s, 2) And _
                                              arr1(i, 3) = arrWS2(s, 3) Then
                boolFound = True: Exit For  'if first three array columns are the same
            End If
        Next s
        If Not boolFound Then               'if first thrree array columns not the same:
            k = k + 1                       'the array row is incremented
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
                arr2(j, k) = arr1(i, j) 'the row is loaded with all the necessary values
            Next j
            'swap the columns 4 and 5 values:
            If arr1(i, 4) = "ABC" And arr1(i, 5) = "XYZ" Then arr2(4, k) = "XYZ": arr2(5, k) = "ABC"
        End If
        boolFound = False              'reinitialize the boolean variable
   End If
 Next i
 
 If k > 0 Then
    'Preserving only the existing array elements:
    ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To UBound(arr1, 2), 1 To k)
    
    'Dropping the array content at once (the fastest way of copying):
    WS2.Range("A" & LR2 + 1).Resize(UBound(arr2, 2), UBound(arr2)).Value = _
                                         WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr2)
    WS2.Activate: WS2.Range("A" & LR2 + 1).Select
    MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
 Else
    MsgBox "No any row to be copied!", vbInformation, "Nothing changed"
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code looks great so far. Have not the chance to test it now. (will do tomorrow). Nevertheless your code is very detailed. I have some more requirements here. So your code will not work for me fully. FIRST: I ve to doublecheck if the row of WS 1 is already in "use" in WS2. If it is in use, then do not copy the line. Coulmn 2 and 3 are my identifiers here. If value in column 2 & 3 are already in WS 2, then don not copy the line. SECOND: If value in Column 4 = ABC and value in column 5 = XYZ then swap the data in WS2. (I will send an update to the original post with a comment)

Comment: @Ben: When you ask a question, you should do it in a way to be answered based on what you requested. Anyhowo, in "use" is a not so clear concept. Do you mean, it exists in `WS2`, too? If yes, what this "existance" mean? That values in columns A, B, C are the same in both sheets? Even if the first column in `WS2` does not contain the search string, should the row be considered that exists? You mentioned only columns 2 and 3. Then, what the "swap" should mean? To swap the values between columns 4 and 5?

Comment: When you say "If value in Column 4 = ABC and value in column 5 = XYZ" are you referring to  `WS1` worksheet?

Comment: U r right. It was not that clear from my side. Will give you a more detailed answer later/tomorrow. 
Really appreciate your answer so far. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben: But I am trying to adapt the code and I asked you to clarify some issues... Can't you do that, since I am only referring to what you supplementary asked?

Comment: @Ben: Did you find some time to test the above code?

Comment: I am sorry, I had no time so far. I will do this tomorrow. But i relly appreciate your help so far.